# Remove Duplicate 3 value Tuples from list of tuples with similar elements

Tags: python, list, loops, set, tuples

I have a list of tuples where each tuple has 3 elements within it:

```
slices = [('location', 'region', 'sub_region'),
 ('location', 'sub_region', ' job_level'),
 ('sub_region', 'region', 'location')]
```

In the above example, the first tuple and the last tuple would be considered duplicates, because the elements within are the same (location, region, sub_region). I'd want to keep only one of them so that my **desired output** would become:

```
[('location', 'region', 'sub_region'),
 ('location', 'sub_region', ' job_level')]
```

I tried to do this with a list comprehension, but my output ends up being an empty list:

```
new_slices = [(x, y, z) for x, y, z in slices if (z, x, y) not in slices]
```

Current Output:

```
new_slices = []
```

Any thoughts on how I might be able to accomplish this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
slices = [('location', 'region', 'sub_region'),
 ('location', 'sub_region', ' job_level'),
 ('sub_region', 'region', 'location')]

set(tuple(sorted(s)) for s in slices)
```

Output- {(' job_level', 'location', 'sub_region'),
('location', 'region', 'sub_region')}

You can convert this to list again, if you want list type

Note, you mentioned the first and last tuples are some. Actually they are not - because "location" and " location" are not same

Comment: The same comment as I added for the other answer. If you run the `print` enough times, you can see `('job_level', 'location', 'sub_region')` as one of the elements (appears to be out of order)

Comment: @rv.kvetch as per the question, he said the first and last tuples in the list are same, which means he does not care about the order of elements inside the tuple. That's why I put this solution

Comment: You are right of course, the order of elements in the tuple does not matter when *comparing* the tuples. however, this solution changes the ordering of *all* tuples within the slice. So for example, the second element can occasionally become out of the order it was originally in.

Comment: In my specific use case, the order of the elements in the tuples does not matter in any of the use cases. @rv.kvetch, great call out that if it DID matter (which I didn't make clear in the question), that this solution would change the order of tuples that had no duplicates.

Answer (score 2):

If changing the order of elements doesn't matter for you can do this without **`sorting`**.

*(with sorting order is **O((n^2)log(n))** but without sorting order is **O(n)**)*

you can use `set` then convert to `tuple` then get as `set` like below:

```
>>> set(tuple(set(slc)) for slc in slices)
{('location', 'sub_region', ' job_level'),
 ('region', 'location', 'sub_region')}

>>> list(set(tuple(set(slc)) for slc in slices))
[('region', 'location', 'sub_region'),
 ('location', 'sub_region', ' job_level')]
```

Comment: This can result in elements in the result list being out of order due to set being an unordered collection. For example, sometimes you can see `('sub_region', 'location', ' job_level')` in the result list.

Comment: OP want check duplicated without considering order of element, I think don't matter the order of elements changing

Comment: @rv.kvetch when you want delete one of these : `('location', 'region', 'sub_region')` or `('sub_region', 'region', 'location')` you keep one of them and you change order of delete element you keep ;)

Comment: @rv.kvetch in your code why don't keep: `('sub_region', 'region', 'location')`?!, I think the order of element don't matter

Comment: @rv.kvetch where? I can't find, he says: **`I'd want to keep only one of them`**